# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ shows a comment where none exists?

Tags: support, status-declined, global-inbox, deleted-comments

My inbox shows a comment on an answer I posted, but when I click on it to go read it, my answer doesn't have any comments (with my apologies for the subject matter):

[image: mysteriously disappearing comment]

Could this be an artifact of the data center move?

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest **not** petting urine stains from the subfloor... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of the data center move.

For a brief period after the sites were up, the Inbox was not fully online.  Any activity that occurred around that time may have issues.

The few affected items won't be fixed, as the circumstances are just too exceptional to merit the time spent.