# Deleted comments still visible in the SuperCollider

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a comment in my inbox that doesn't exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/why-is-there-a-comment-in-my-inbox-that-doesnt-exist)

I'd be surprised if I'm the only one that noticed this (so it is likely a dupe), but I couldn't find any other questions on here that describe what I'm seeing.

They say a picture's worth a thousand words (so I'll give you two):

[image]

[image]

The comment text that is showing in [the SuperCollider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838) is different than any of the comments on the answer (so I assume it has been deleted). Shouldn't it really only say one comment, with the text for the comment that is on the answer?

UPDATE - Even now that there are additional comments on the answer, the count is still wrong (total of three comments not posted by me, but the box says four comments).

UPDATE - This is a possible dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68445/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-shows-a-comment-where-none-exists) question, but unless the datacenter moved again, its answer is not helpful.

As requested. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843429/635634) is the answer to which the comments were left (and subsequently deleted). I'm not really sure how to link to the SuperCollider though...

I realize it isn't something to stops the site from operating, just a general annoyance since the information is inaccurate. Is there any chance of it getting fixed?

Comment: 2000 words? tl;dr

Comment: This behaviour was known, and used to be (ab)used as a form of private messaging by many members. However, I seem to remember that it was supposed to have been "fixed" at some point...

Comment: @CodyGray - Oh well, your loss ;)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - I've noticed it in the past on and off. I'm not sure if there is a niche condition causing it.

Comment: The menu's called [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/134300) or just "the supercollider" for short.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Thanks. Question updated! :)

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ - I hadn't realized that tag was related. Perhaps a more logical alias tag would make it more obvious.

Comment: @M.Babcock Well, the tag is synonym'd to [stackexchange-menu]

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ - Given the official name of the menu, I would have assumed something more logical (not that I would have guessed it anyway without knowing the official name). Perhaps that'll be my next question :D